# A connection attempt failed

Tags: php

Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://www.ibnlive.com/rss/india.xml): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\connectivity\15july\ibnlive\ibnparser.php on line 32

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.ibnlive.com/rss/india.xml" in C:\xampp\htdocs\connectivity\15july\ibnlive\ibnparser.php on line 32

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\connectivity\15july\ibnlive\ibnparser.php on line 32

Comment: Increase timeout for script `set_time_limit`

Answer (score 0):

You are facing script execution timeout problem.

Write this line to begging of your file.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);
//180 is seconds = 3 minutes
```

OR

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

You can also set timeout value in php.ini file

```
max_execution_time = 180 ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds (I CHANGED THIS VALUE)
max_input_time = 120     ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
```

You can also set timeout in your .htaccess file(root directory) by adding this line:-

```
php_value max_execution_time 180  //where 180 is seconds = 3 minutes
```

Hope it will help you :)